# Forcing to list a co-author that did not contribute after publishing

Tags: publications, ethics, authorship, legal-issues

We published a paper, me as first and corresponding author. There was a technician who repeatedly refused to work, did useless measurements after having been forced, which he never evaluated and basically said "help yourself", never had a look at the publication during working on it, and now tries to force the group leaders to be included as co-author afterwards by lying about his contributions (still, he would have done no intellectual work but was pipetting down my protocols). Data integrity steps are not provided by the institute, so everyone could copy measurement files from the shared server. The group leaders want me to give in although they agreed with me on the phone, just because they fear more consequences from him than from me, since I was nice so far. Now I don't see why I should constantly reward such a person.

1. The paper is published. They agreed. Can they even force me if I (and another co-author) say no?
2. Would - by your experience - the journal be willing to amend at all?
3. Can he/they force me legally? I am not even employed there anymore.
4. Do I have to prove anything after publication? Can someone claim data from a shared server anyway? Is it my turn to (re)act?
5. Would you do some "preparing steps" from my side if not willing to give in?
6. Do you have any advice from former experience?

Kind regards and thanks for any help!

Comment: I think you will have a hard time arguing to the journal why an author should be added *at this stage*, and it will make your and your group look bad.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excluding a coauthor based on data misuse and misrepresentation?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/97226/excluding-a-coauthor-based-on-data-misuse-and-misrepresentation)

Answer (score 2):

You might take a look [here](https://publicationethics.org/case/new-claim-authorship-published-paper); and as for a more detailed response, let me focus on this one question:

> Would you do some "preparing steps" from my side if not willing to give in?

You could ask everyone to tell you which contributions they offered based on the [Contributor Roles Taxonomy (CRediT)](https://casrai.org/credit/). And make sure that the CRediTs are visible in the publication as well.

On the one hand, it is possible that they will hesitate to point out their contribution in case they do not find anything worthwhile to pick from CRediT. On the other hand, you might actually end up finding one minuscule contribution of that co-author that does merit a mention according to CRediT. The "objectified" nature of CRediT might help to resolve such conflicts.

And if you have the CRediTs published as well, then the readership will at least know the variation in efforts of each co-author.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is perilleous to make a judgement on this one-sided story, especially regarding the point

> There was a technician who repeatedly refused to work, did useless
> measurements after having been forced, which he never evaluated

I do not know your former lab policy, but a technician is just a technician: he should just provide you working tool, but he has not to do any research himself (see the technicians like a car mechanic fixing your car, but not driving it: yes, you can fix the car yourself, yes you **have** to check yourself that the car is in working condition).

Said this, the issue "Data integrity steps are not provided by the institute, so everyone could copy measurement files from the shared server." is not an issue, unless you think the technician will try to demonstrate he collected the data and that you stole them (can you provide a proof you collected the data? do you have any mail where you discuss the data collection /results with your professor?).

I would courteously ignore the technician request, although it is possible he may have some ground in asking to be part of the authors'lists.

If you cannot find an hard rule about authorship in the journal rules (something that states "authors'list cannot be modified after submission), I suggest you two steps:

- write the editor asking if there is the possibility of updating the authors'list after submission (and acceptance, if I understood correctly);
- forward the negative answer to all the authors and the technician;

If the editor shows some opening to changing the authors, do the Pontius Pilate way: write the publisher, with the technician and all other co-authors in cc asking if you can add an author to the list of authors. Without motivating it, just asking it.
See how it evolves. In the end, it is a paper and you are just the first author, if the co-authors think the technician contribution deserves authorship, let it be ...

Answer (score 0):

Technically, and it is generally honored, a journal needs every author's consent on the paper to be published at all. The implication of that is that they can probably, or at least *possibly*, force the withdrawal of the paper, but not a change that you don't agree with. This assumes the editor is both knowledgeable about the situation and ethical. An amendment to the paper requires everyone's consent. And if it is literally already published, an editor would be reluctant at best to make a change, especially in the face of a dispute.

They can, perhaps, make your life miserable in other ways, depending on your current position. You will have to evaluate the seriousness of any such threat. But it won't be a *legal* threat.